# Android 6.0 instagram image sharing using intent not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, instagram

I have this code that works fine on other versions of android but seems  like its misbehaving on android 6.0.

There is no error as such but the image is not posted.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
        if (intent != null)
        {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
            try {
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imagePath, "I am Happy", "Share happy !")));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

            startActivity(shareIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            // bring user to the market to download the app.
            // or let them choose an app?
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+"com.instagram.android"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have the same error. Instagram has all permissions but sharing is not working. Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

As Amir suggested, You need to allow permissions to each and every app for every feature. Steps : Android settings -> apps -> select app -> permissions -> allow all those permissions that you want to share.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of Instagram permissions. You have to allow storage in:
Android settings -> apps -> Instagram -> permissions

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is because of android permissions. They have some changes in android 6. Check [this link](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) to understand. Go to the device settings>apps and select your app then accept permissions manually and check if your problem is solved.

Comment: OK, it will sound funny but now intent posting through android app to instagram stopped working. I tried it in morning and everything worked fine the image got posted but now it does not seem to do so, Though there is no error. I have given all permissions  to instagram application. and using api:22

Comment: Check if you revoke the permissions

Comment: I did, check even reinstalled.. does not seem to be working